# Problem Adding URL (as string) to array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, url, loops

This is the problem code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://photostiubhart.comoj.com/ReadGallery/stiubhart1readgallery.php"];
NSError* error; 
NSString* sizeString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
double myDouble = [sizeString doubleValue];
int myInt = (int)(myDouble + (myDouble>0 ? 0.5 : -0.5));

//Create an array to hold the URLS
NSMutableArray *myURLS;

//Initialize the array with nil
myURLS = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSLog(@"Here1");
//Add all the URLs from the server to the array
for (int i = 0; i <= myInt; i++){
    NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat : @"http://photostiubhart.comoj.com/GalleryImages/%dstiubhart1.jpg", i];
    [myURLS addObject: [NSURL URLWithString:tempString]];
    [tempString release];
}

myPhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < myInt; i++){
    [myPhotos addObject:[myURLS objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

It gives the error:

2011-06-21 22:20:47.167 CHARLIE[666:207] -[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x70418c0

This is what the code does (at least supposed to):

1. Generate an integer from the contents of the URL ("4").
2. Use the integer in the for loops to add objects to arrays.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong here?

Thanks a lot,

Jack

Comment: That error isn't being produced by the code you've posted - it means that at some point, you send the `length` message to an NSURL object. There are no calls to `length` in your code. Can you post more about the error, or more of your code in this context?

Comment: is there some other code where you are asking for the NSURLs length?

Comment: is a negative value expected on `myDouble`? the loops are testing slightly different conditions.  it looks like you just want `myPhotos = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:myURLS]`.  can you determine which line is giving you that error?  (it's indicative of over released objects or inappropriate casting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add URLs as strings then shouldn't this –

```
for (int i = 0; i <= myInt; i++){
    NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat : @"http://photostiubhart.comoj.com/GalleryImages/%dstiubhart1.jpg", i];
    [myURLS addObject: [NSURL URLWithString:tempString]];
    [tempString release];
}
```

be –

```
for (int i = 0; i <= myInt; i++){
    NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://photostiubhart.comoj.com/GalleryImages/%dstiubhart1.jpg", i];
    [myURLS addObject:tempString];
}
```

You're probably expecting them to be strings and later calling `length` method on them whereas they are stored as URLs in the array.

*Additionally*, `myPhotos` seems to be a property in which case you can substitute -

```
myPhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < myInt; i++){
    [myPhotos addObject:[myURLS objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

with this -

```
self.myPhotos = myURLS;
[myURLS release]; // To balance out the earlier alloc-init
```